# Youtube SPFJS dynamic nav

Tags: php, jquery, html, youtube

Basically I am trying to implement the youtube spfjs (
https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/documentation/start/) dynamic navigation with progress bar.

I need a php/jquery version of this ruby solution  -http://lorefnon.me/2015/11/26/boost-your-content-focussed-site-with-structured-page-fragments.html

Having issues handling the ?spf=navigate request and returning json files etc. My json file contents isnt loading over the initial page contents.

I've had a look through all online docs etc but really limited information currently out there. Hopefully this will help quite a few people as it seems an awesome framework. Thanks